# KML File into Google Bigquery

Tags: google-maps, google-bigquery, gis, kml

I have a [KML file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jJSeW3klKUF0_T53luvWHFQi6EtV7zjS/view?usp=sharing) that I exported after making my own Google Map. I was wondering if anyone knows a way I can get this map into BigQuery as a table of the Precinct name and the coordinates of their borders? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this solution is for shapefiles, but it works for KML files as well (with proper flag changes): https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-geographic-data-like-zipcode-boundaries-into-bigquery-25e4be4391c8

Answer (score 2):

You can't load KML directly into a BigQuery [GEOGRAPHY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#geography_type) column. But BigQuery *does* support loading from [WKT, WKB or GeoJSON](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#loading_geospatial_data).

So you'll have to first convert the KML into one of the above formats, perhaps using [GDAL](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)?

After that you can run a `bq load`. Alternatively to a load, it also works well as an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources), for example with WKB embedded as one column in a CSV.